# Ensuring Gradle Task always runs regardless of results from dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies

How can I ensure that the downstream "validate" task executes even when build task throws a horrible error?

I want all of these possible flows to be possible:

- build -> test -> validate
- build (error) -> validate
- build -> test (error) -> validate

What I find is that **GradleException** and **TaskExecutionException** result in a full stop with no further task execution, **StopActionException** doesn't prevent test from executing.

Sample Code:

```
task build(){
  doFirst() {
    println "building..."
    throw new GradleException("Gradle exc")
  }
}

task test(){
  mustRunAfter 'build'
  doFirst() {
    println "testing..."
  }
}


task validate() {
  doFirst() {
    println "validating..."
  }
}


task buildPlan(dependsOn:[build,test]) {}
buildPlan.finalizedBy(validate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone know if this would leave out build steps?

If I use a task with its own try catch and call execute on each task then it works as I want.

```
task build(){
  doFirst() {
    println "building..."
    throw new GradleException("Gradle exc")
  }
}

task test(){
  mustRunAfter 'build'
  doFirst() {
    println "testing..."
  }
}


task validate() {
  doFirst() {
    println "validating..."
  }
}


// Validate Called Reliably
task buildWithCatch {
  doFirst {
    try {
      build.execute()
      test.execute()
    }
    finally {
      validate.execute()
    }
  }
}

// Validate Never Called
task buildPlan(dependsOn:[build,test]) {}
buildPlan.finalizedBy(validate)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case both 'build' and 'test' need to be `finalizedBy` 'validate'. The 'buildPlan' task unfortunately won't be executed if either 'build' or 'test' fail therefore the 'validate' task will never run.

Comment: that is unfortunate because I want validate to run after test and not between build and test.   I guess, I need jenkins or something else to run the task.  Or I could have a task that runs build,test in a try catch with a finally clause

Comment: The 'validate' task **will** run after 'test'. A task can never run more than once so if two tasks are finalized by the same task, it will run after both of them.